# Webcam not working since upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: usb, macos, webcam

I have a Creative Labs webcam (VF0700) that was working fine on Yosemite, but since the upgrade to OS X 10.11, it has stopped working.
It is recognised under the System Report in 'About this mac' and if I shut the mac down, plug it into the USB port before rebooting, it works fine ... until I unplug it and then it doesn't work again.

I have asked Creative support, and they say 'it's not supported' but the fact that it works with a reboot gives me some hope that there may be a workaround and I don't want to have to buy a new webcam for the odd few times that the iSight camera is not suitable.

Is there a command I can use to force the USB port to restart (as if I rebooted the Mac) or some other method I can use to get the webcam working without needing to do a complete reboot each time?

Comment: For the builtin camera, `sudo killall VDCAssistant` worked for me (found on apple dev forums). Not sure if that works for external cameras too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried each combination I can think of (execute the command with camera plugged in, unplugged etc) and its still not recognised.

Comment: I have the same camera and the same problem on High Sierra - any update on what you did here? Time to buy a new camera?

Answer (score 2):

- Open activity monitor
- Search for `usbmuxd`
- Click on terminate process
- Enter Admin password if required
- Reinsert your usb device

This worked for me a while back when my usb modem wasn't working on Yosemite.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I have tried it this morning but unfortunately it hasn't worked for me. I can see the process end, and restart, but it still does not detect the webcam. Thanks anyway :)